# Calculating angle of attack and relative air velocity for 3DoF simulations

Tags: aerospace-engineering

I am working with a 3DoF simulator to implement dynamics mentioned in this paper: "Reusable Launchers: Development of a Coupled Flight Mechanics, Guidance, and Control Benchmark" which is actually a 6DoF approach (statics+dynamics).

When they calculate the angle of attack, they use the relative air velocity, which is an **inertial frame velocity** minus the **cross product of the earth rotation vector and the inertial frame position**, and some term for **wind perturbations**. The problem is that in order to convert this to the body frame to get the relative air velocity for drag calculations you need to work with the body frame, which means that you need the aerodynamic angles of roll, pitch , and yaw. How else can I calculate the drag from my model which works in the **local vertical local horizontal** frame?

Comment: If I understand correctly your simulation is just a 2D plane simulation, involving translation around x (horizontal) and y(vertical) and rotation about z?

Comment: @NMech No, it is a 3D simulation, with the body x axis representing the pointing direction of the rocket, which I assume the simplest approximation for angle to attack to make is to consider the angle between the thrust direction and velocity- this breaks down however when you are not thrusting.